# When i enable google login in my asp.net app, i get no default scheme error

Tags: asp.net-core, authentication, authorization, google-oauth

I'm adding google auth in asp.net application. previously i had microsoft auth and it's working fine. I copied same code and chnaged reqired settings to google client id and scheme.
But i'm getting : No authenticationScheme was specified, and there was no DefaultChallengeScheme found. The default schemes can be set using either AddAuthentication(string defaultScheme) or AddAuthentication(Action configureOptions) error.
Not able to figure out why?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JtjMW.png)

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.DefaultChallengeScheme = GoogleDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.DefaultChallengeScheme = MicrosoftAccountDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            })
            .AddCookie(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options => options.AccessDeniedPath = "/Auth/Unauthorized")
            .AddGoogle(GoogleDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
            {
                options.ClientId = googleSettings.ClientId;
                options.ClientSecret = googleSettings.ClientSecret;
                options.CallbackPath = "/signin-google";

                options.Events = new()
                {
                    OnTicketReceived = async context =>
                    {
                        void AccessDenied()
                        {
                            context.Response.Redirect("/Auth/Unauthorized");
                            context.Fail("You are not allowed");
                            context.HandleResponse();
                        }

                        var userService = context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<IUsersServices>();
                        var claimsIdentity = context.Principal.Identity as ClaimsIdentity;

                        var userEmail = claimsIdentity.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Email).Value;
                        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(userEmail))
                        {
                            AccessDenied();
                            return;
                        }
                        var user = await userService.GetUserByEmailAsync(userEmail);
                        if (user is null)
                        {
                            AccessDenied();
                            return;
                        }

                        claimsIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, user.Role.ToString()));
                        context.Success();
                    },
                    OnRedirectToAuthorizationEndpoint = context =>
                    {
                        // this will avoid automatic re-login when signing out
                        context.Response.Redirect(context.RedirectUri + "&prompt=consent");
                        return Task.CompletedTask;
                    }
                };
            })
            .AddMicrosoftAccount(MicrosoftAccountDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
            {
                options.ClientId = microsoftSettings.ClientId;
                options.ClientSecret = microsoftSettings.ClientSecret;
                options.CallbackPath = "/signin-microsoft";
                options.Events = new()
                {
                    OnTicketReceived = async context =>
                    {
                        void AccessDenied()
                        {
                            context.Response.Redirect("/Auth/Unauthorized");
                            context.Fail("You are not allowed");
                            context.HandleResponse();
                        }

                        var userService = context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<IUsersServices>();
                        var claimsIdentity = context.Principal.Identity as ClaimsIdentity;

                        var userEmail = claimsIdentity.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Email).Value;
                        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(userEmail))
                        {
                            AccessDenied();
                            return;
                        }
                        var user = await userService.GetUserByEmailAsync(userEmail);
                        if (user is null)
                        {
                            AccessDenied();
                            return;
                        }

                        claimsIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, user.Role.ToString()));
                        context.Success();
                    },
                    OnRedirectToAuthorizationEndpoint = context =>
                    {
                        // this will avoid automatic re-login when signing out
                        context.Response.Redirect(context.RedirectUri + "&prompt=consent");
                        return Task.CompletedTask;
                    }
                };
            });

            services.AddAuthorization(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy(Constants.Interviewer, pb => pb.RequireClaim(ClaimTypes.Role, Constants.Interviewer, Constants.Recruiter, Constants.Admin));
                options.AddPolicy(Constants.Recruiter, pb => pb.RequireClaim(ClaimTypes.Role, Constants.Recruiter, Constants.Admin));
                options.AddPolicy(Constants.Admin, pb => pb.RequireClaim(ClaimTypes.Role, Constants.Admin));
                options.AddPolicy(Constants.SuperUser, pb => pb.RequireClaim(ClaimTypes.Role, Constants.SuperUser));
            });
```

Note: I have [Authorize] attribute on my controller and I'm basically prompting login for my controller page using that [Authorize] if user is not signed in to app. So can't remove authorize.
Tried some stack overflow solutions but nothing differs.

Comment: Could not reproduce,could you upload a minimal example that could reproduce this issue?

Comment: It makes no sense to assign two scheme to  options.DefaultChallengeScheme,but since you've assigned  DefaultChallengeScheme ,it's really strange the error occoured

Comment: Since ChallengeAsync method was called  in your stacktrace,It seems that you haven't authenticate with the default scheme,have you tried to Specific the Scheme with your Authorize Attribute？